# How to show star at first two character of a string in oracle query?

Tags: oracle

Example if an ID is 1213 i want show **13.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a number

```
select '**' || substr(to_char(id),3)
  from my_table
```

Or, if it's already a character

```
select '**' || substr(id,3)
  from my_table
```

This concatenates `**` onto the beginning of the string, using the Oracle concatenation operator `||` and removes the first two characters of the `id` using [`substr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php).

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1f06/2)  to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sacrifice performance too much, to mask first two characters you can use-

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('1213','(.)2','**') from dual; --if VARCHAR

MASKED
------------
**13

SQL> select regexp_replace(1213,'(.)2','**') from dual;  --if NUMBER

MASKED
------------
**13
```

`REGEXP_REPLACE` will work alike on `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR` so you save some conversion time there.

Consecutively, you can create a [Function Based Index](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_regular_expressions_tuning_index.htm) on the `regexp` function operation to optimize the query like (considering you would always want to mask only first two characters of `ID`) -

```
CREATE INDEX
   mask_id
ON
   table_name
 (regexp_replace(id,'(.)2','**'));
```